# How can we use two datasets(dates) in rdlc expression using vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, rdlc

dataset1:

```
from 01-03-2023 till end of the month
```

dataset2: Holidays list

```
05-03-2023
12-03-2023
19-03-2023
26-03-2023
```

Could someone help me out how to give expression for these datasets. when I tried to give expression

```
=SUM(First(Fields!Idate.Value, "DataSet1"))-SUM(First(Fields!Date.Value, "DataSet2"))
```

dataset2 showing error line. I want result how many present days count in dataset1

Thank you...

Comment: Edit your post explain what you are trying to report.  You are showing sum of DATE fields which makes no sense for what appears to be March 1 - March 31, 2023.  Why not merge the data with holidays into one table for the report vs split with some flag indicating holiday vs normal data.  Then, sum actual data content.  Your sample makes no sense otherwise to me.

Comment: @DRapp, I'm creating school attendance report. In this lost column trying to get number of working days using rdlc. so I'm trying to subtracting. Thank you..

Comment: @Smith You would want the `COUNT` of the days, not the sum of the dates. Also, you would probably find a calendar table to be of immense use, e.g., [Designing a Calendar Table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/).